# Replace Values of Multiple Columns in Pandas Dataframe More Efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame, `df`,  where I would like to replace several values

| user1 | user2 | user3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | yoo | apple |
| mango | ram | mango |

Instead of doing

```
df['user1'] = df['user1'].replace(['apple','mango'], [0, 1])
df['user3'] = df['user1'].replace(['apple','mango'], [0, 1])
df['user2'] = df['user2'].replace(['yoo','ram'], [2, 3])
```

to get the final DataFrame of

| user1 | user2 | user3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |

Is there any way I make the code above more efficient such that I can change the values of apple, mango, yoo and ram with one line of code?

Comment: Something like `df.replace(['apple', 'mango', 'yoo', 'ram'], [0, 1, 2, 3])` works? Unless you actually need different mappings in different columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need set range by unique values per columns use:

```
cols = ['user1','user2','user3']
s = df[cols].unstack()
df[cols] = pd.Series(pd.factorize(s)[0], index=s.index).unstack(0)
print (df)
   user1  user2  user3
0      0      2      0
1      1      3      1
```